# Resharper with large or *very* large files

Tags: c#, exception, linq-to-sql, resharper

I just wanted to know your experience with using resharper.
We have a very heavy dbml file as our database has many tables and every time I need to open up that file I start getting lots of exception coming from resharper. Has anyone had that problem before? If yes, what did you do to fix this very ANNOYING problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I use [<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2008/08/06/how-to-disable-resharper-for-a-file-ctrl-8.aspx) to disable resharper for a file.

As of ReSharper 5 this was [changed](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/284638) to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>.

Comment: Great, I hope I can remember that.  I sometimes have problems with ReSharper as well.